# fread issue with archive package unzip file in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am having issues while trying to use fread, after I unzip a file using the archive package in R. The data I am using can be downloaded from https://www.kaggle.com/c/favorita-grocery-sales-forecasting/data

The code is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(devtools)
library(archive)
library(data.table)
setwd("C:/jc/2017/13.Lafavorita")
hol<-archive("./holidays_events.csv.7z")
holcsv<-fread(hol$path, header = T, sep = ",")
```

This code gives the error message:

```
File 'holidays_events.csv' does not exist. Include one or more spaces to consider the input a system command.
```

Yet if I try:

```
holcsv1<-read.csv(archive_read(hol),header = T,sep = ",")
```

It works perfectly. I need to use the fread command because the other data bases I need to open are too big to use read.csv. I am puzzled because my code was working fine a few days ago. I could unzip the files manually, but that is not the point. I have tried to solve this problem for hours, but I cannot seem to find anything useful on the documentation. I found this: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/man/knit.Rd#L104-L107 , but I cannot understand it.

Comment: The error message suggests that the file `holidays_events.csv` was not unzipped properly. If this is case, then the error is not related at all to `fread` from `data.table`. What is the value of `hol$path`? Can you locate the file it corresponds to, and make sure that it contains what it should?

Comment: The archive command produces a tibble (1x3) that contains the **path**, the size, and the date of the unzipped file. So `hol$path` produces `"holidays_events.csv"` which is the name of the unzipped file. Yet, for some reason the fread function is not reading the current wd, it seems to read the file from a different directory (or that is my guess).

Comment: Turns out the answer is rather simple, but I found it by luck. So after using the `archive` function you need to pass it to the `archive_extract` function. So in my case, I should add the following to the code: `hol1<-archive_extract(hol)` . Then I have to change the last line to: `holcsv<-fread(hol1$path, header = T, sep = ",")`. Thanks a lot @Jealie, your comment helped me a lot, I was focusing on the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is rather simple, but I found it by luck. So after using the archive function you need to pass it to the `archive_extract` function. So in my case, I should add the following to the code: `hol1<-archive_extract(hol)` . Then I have to change the last line to: `holcsv<-fread(hol1$path, header = T, sep = ",")`